# Listing items in a nested list in Python

Tags: python, list, recursion

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Flatten (an irregular) list of lists in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2158395/flatten-an-irregular-list-of-lists-in-python)

I wanted a solution to list/print all the items in a nested list (with arbitrary nesting level). Here is what I came up with:

```
items = []
def getitems(mylist):
    for item in mylist:
        if type(item) is list:
            getitems(item)
        else:
            items.append(item)
    return items
```

Sample output:

```
foo=['foo','bar',['foo','bar','baz'],'spam',['ham','eggs','salami']]

In [8]: getitems(foo)
Out[8]: 
['foo',
 'bar',
 'foo',
 'bar',
 'foo',
 'bar',
 'baz',
 'spam',
 'ham',
 'eggs',
 'salami']
```

Is this a good solution? Or is there a better approach?

Comment: I think you want to post that on http://codereview.stackexchange.com/ . Otherwise, it looks good to me.

Comment: Looks good, you might change the `type(item) is list` to `isinstance(item, list)`. Also note that there is a recursion depth limit which is by default is 1000.

Comment: Thanks for the isinstance tip!

Answer (score 0):

This might be a bit pedantic, but you could pass the accumulator list as an optional argument. This way you don't have any global variables lying a round and avoid possible issues when you call the function twice and forgot to clear it after the first call:

```
def getitems(mylist, acc = None):
    if acc is None: acc = []
    for item in mylist:
        if type(item) is list:
            getitems(item, acc)
        else:
            acc.append(item)
    return acc
```

Comment: You should never put an empty list (or any other mutable object) as defualt parameter to a function in Python. It is one of the language's greatest pitfalls.

Comment: Use `def getitems(mylist, acc=None):` and inside the body `if acc is None: acc = []` instead.

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out. I updated my answer. Could you please explain why using mutable data as default parameters are a bad idea?

Comment: The issue is that default parameters get evaluated once, when the function is defined.  Any changes made to the default parameter persist in subsequent calls to the function.

Comment: Thanks! I found [an old blog post](http://effbot.org/zone/default-values.htm) that discusses the issue in some detail.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2158395/flatten-an-irregular-list-of-lists-in-python for the best way of doing this. This question should be closed as duplicate anyway, awaiting two more votes